# Helium Balloon Experiment

Tags: gravity

We tied a helium filled balloon to a counterweight and it floats aimlessly in the room. I asked if the balloon were to be outside the building (all things considered no wind same temperature) would the balloon float at the same level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The height at which the balloon floats is determined by the density of the air outside of the balloon. Once you are high enough in the air that upward force generated by the difference in densities $\rho_{\text{helium}}$ and $\rho_{\text{air}}$ is exactly canceled by the gravitational force on the balloon plus its counterweight, the balloon will remain at the same height (assuming it has negligible upward velocity, else it'll overshoot a little, then come back down and oscillate around the equilibrium height).

Now, inside a room, we may assume that the density of the air is the same as outside. Therefore, your balloon will float at the same level, regardless of whether you are inside a room or not.

Answer (score 0):

If sunlight hits the balloon it will warm, expand, and be more buoyant than when it was when in the room.